# Connecting 2 external monitors and 1 laptop using a docking station

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dell-latitude, docking-station

[image]

I am trying to connect 2 external monitors with the Dell Docking Station. I have a Dell Latitude E6230 laptop. Now I have connected both of the monitors or external displays through the docking station. All 3 of them are running when I change **Output To**, but at that very instant I can see only 2 of the 3.

Comment: Exactly which docking station model is in question?  How are each of the monitors connected (what kind of ports are being used)?  Are you saying that in the Display Properties you can see all three displays listed, but can only pick two of them at a time?  Are you trying to clone or extend the desktop?  Are all monitors identified (resolution and name) correctly?

Comment: Tehcie007 . Sorry I cant see name of Docking station . Its a Dell one. For one VGA is used and not sure about second one. But I have attached the pic here. I can see all of the three displays in the display property. I want to extend the laptop. Yes all are identified correctly. Thanks for help. I am complete noob in this field.

Comment: Which of the 2 you can only see? Which is the one that doesn't work?

Comment: Both of them works. The only problem is not simultaneously. I want Laptop and other two Monitor to be in action at the same time.

Comment: Which graphics does it have; Intel HD 3000 or Intel HD 4000? HD 2500 & 3000 do not support 3 monitors [per Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/04/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&docid=584364).

Comment: Its HD 4000 as per dxdiag command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got solved through **USB display adopter** which either you can buy through Amazon or any other retailer.